# How to use WHERE and LIKE clause with JOIN statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to perform a `JOIN` on two tables, which works fine by itself. But if I then try to add a `WHERE x LIKE '%abc%'`, it doesn't work.

For example:

```
SELECT tbd.primarytitle, trd.averagerating  
FROM tbd  
INNER JOIN trd 
ON tbd.tconst = trd.tconst 
WHERE tbd.primarytitle LIKE '%A%'
```

I've tried going through all kinds of joins, and I've tried parenthesizing the first part and assigning to a table, then performing the `WHERE` x `LIKE` on that table, and no luck.

How can I achieve this? I've tried looking at 6-7 articles but none of them address both `WHERE` and `LIKE` after a `JOIN`.

Comment: Table structure and some sample data rows would help here. Does your query return rows without the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @JacobH Yeah... if I just do an inner join with the code above then it returns all rows from both tables. But once I add the WHERE is when nothing returns.

Comment: Maybe you dont have any data in the tbd table with A in it?  If you provide sample data that helps

Comment: @Brad The tables I'm using are from IMDb records. I'm trying to target Star Wars: A New Hope, which is listed in the primarytitle column, and the accompanying rating with the film. There are hundreds and hundreds of records with 'A' in the primary title field.

Comment: @Brad If I take away the LIKE and just use an exact match though, such as tbd.primarytitle = 'Star Wars: A New Hope' then it works.

Comment: There would not be any data which satisfies the where condition mentioned.

Comment: Take away the join and do a simple: `SELECT primarytitle FROM tbd WHERE primarytitle LIKE '%A%'`. Do you get any results?

Comment: @forpas Nope.. figured it out though. Forgot that in Access the wildcard is asterisk and not percent.

Comment: And you also forgot to mention or tag your question with Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the environment being used for the SQL. In MS Access, you have to use `*` instead of `%` for wildcards. Simply switch the two and the query will return records.

Comment: This is why you should always include this information in the post and tag it properly!

Comment: You're right, my bad... it's been a long time since I've used Access. Hopped on real quick to test join speeds against H2 DB for a Java app I'm working on. I feel silly =P